# Ceiling fan/light install with dual switch help

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan

I have 2 switched for my ceiling unit and light and fan only work on 1 of the switches not both like it should. I had just a light fixture installed. I bought a fan/light combo and I have 2 wall switches. This unit has a remote module built into it.

Coming from the ceiling I have, a bare ground,a white, a red, and a black (capped off not connected to light).

I currently have the 2 green wires from the unit attached to the bare, 
white to white,
black to black,
blue(from fan) to red from ceiling.

I have switched the black and blue wires around and it will only work from one switch or the other when I switch the wires.

I have looked at my living room fan combo and it’s working right and it’s wired the same. What am I doing wrong?  Any help it’s greatly appreciated as I am a new home owner and learning.

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you want to control the fan from the remote?  Or from the wall switches?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch and fan boxes please?